# JAVA 8 and Instant truncateTo bug

Tags: java-8

I have noted while trying to refactor code that the following code :

```
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Could be refactored to :

```
System.out.println(Date.from(new Date().toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)));
```

But here the issues :

```
Wed Aug 25 16:16:22 CEST 2021
Wed Aug 25 00:00:00 CEST 2021
Wed Aug 25 02:00:00 CEST 2021
```

First line is the original date, second is old code output but the third is the output of truncate method. Am I doing something wrong or truncate is supposed to return non zero result (in my case ).
Please advise.

Comment: My guess is that the calendar was set to the `CEST` timezone (either explicitly or implicitly through system defaults). When `toInstant` is called, the date is interpreted as `UTC` date. Since `CEST` is `UTC + 2`, it then displays `02:00:00` as time.

Comment: I would recommend to forego using `java.util.Date` alltogether and instead use the `java.time` API. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/akoAuY)

Answer (score 1):

The [specification of `Instant.truncatedTo(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) clearly says:

> The fields are calculated on the basis of using a `UTC` offset as seen in `toString`.

When you print the value using `Date.toString` rather than `Instant.toString`, it will be printed using the system’s default timezone, which obviously differs from UTC in your system.

To truncate to days according to your system’s default timezone, you have to perform the truncation on a `ZonedDateTime` using the right timezone. E.g., using your code as starting point

```java
System.out.println(Date.from(
    new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toInstant()));
```

This produces your desired result, however, bears quite a lot of conversions. The raises the question what you actually need or why you aren’t using the `java.time` API in the first place.

The result of the expression `ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)` is already a date/time truncated to days in the current timezone. You should perform whatever operation you actually intend to do directly on this object.

If your operation truly is printing and you insist on getting exactly the same output as `Date.toString()` would provide, you can use, e.g.

```java
System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT,"%tc%n", ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```

If, however, a `Date` provided by some legacy software is your starting point, there is no way around the `Instant` step,

```
System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT, "%tc%n",
    date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS));
```